# 'flutter_background_service' android-34 crash

Tags: background, location, background-service, background-fetch, flutter-background

I'm using the flutter_background_service package to write a service to run in the background in flutter, and I get an error when I get the hour build.

Execution failed for task ':flutter_background_service_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_background_service_android:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: /Users/alihangedik/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/android.jar.
> > /Users/alihangedik/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/android.jar

I'm using the flutter_background_service package to write a service to run in the background in flutter, and I get an error when I get the hour build.